# Relationship between signature of a surface and Euler characteristic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a two dimensional smooth, projective, connected variety over complex numbers. Let $\omega_X$ denote the canonical divisor of $X$. Let $\nu$ be the class of a divisor. In the proof of Corollary 12.1.4 in Le Potier's Lectures on Vector bundles he writes that

$$P(\nu)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\nu -\frac{\omega_X}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{8}{\rm sign}(X) \qquad \qquad ---- (*)$$

On the preceding page he mentions that

$$P(\nu)=\chi(\mathcal{O}_X) + \frac{1}{2}(\nu^2-\nu.\omega_X)\,.$$

Combining these we get that $(*)$ is equivalent to

$$\chi(\mathcal O_X)=\frac{1}{8}(\omega_X^2-{\rm sign}(X))\qquad \qquad ---- (**)\,.$$

Using Noether's formula which says that $12\chi(\mathcal O_X)=\omega_X^2+e$, where $e$ is the topological Euler characteristic, we get that $(*)$ and $(**)$ are equivalent to proving that
$$4\chi(\mathcal O_X)=e+{\rm sign}(X)\qquad \qquad ----(***)\,.$$
How do we prove any one of the equivalent statements $(*), (**)$ or $(***)$.

Comment: Is Corollary 12.1.4 not proved in those lectures?

Comment: @Lee Mosher: He mentions the assertion $(*)$ and uses it in the proof of Corollary 12.1.4.

Comment: I see. Your clarifying edit helps.